# Will previous 301 redirect still be cached if site switches to using SSL?

Tags: redirect, ssl, browser-cache

For reasons only my past self knows I put a 301 redirect in place to force all traffic to `example.org` from `www.example.org`. Put simply it dropped the `www.` subdomain.

Now I would like to change it so that all traffic goes to the `www.` subdomain, which would be problematic as any cached 301s in user's browsers would send the user into a redirect loop.

So I am planning on buying an SSL certificate and encrypting all traffic on the site - for other reasons too. If I redirect the users to `https://www.example.org/` will it still cause the browser to look at it's cache and go into a redirect loop again?

To my mind `https://www.example.org` is a different URL to `http://www.example.org`, but do all the browsers see it this way for caching purposes?

Comment: *"I am planning on buying an SSL certificate..."* - You might try [Startcom](http://www.startcom.org/) or [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/). They offer free Class 1 server certificates. The certificates are trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers. Class 1's are domain validated via email and *don't* allow wildcards. If you need a wildcard, then you'll have to purchase a Class 2 or higher. Startcom and CAcert charge for revocation, if needed.

Comment: @jww Thanks for the links, but CACert aren't distributed with browsers so they throw warnings and Startcom is always down - besides [Gandi](http://gandi.net) include a free cert with all domain registrations or transfers so I just transferred my domain over to them.

Comment: Browsers have their own built-in CA Zoo (i.e., `cacerts.pem`). See, for example, [iOS 7: List of available trusted root certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5012). Startcom is trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers. See, for example, [Definitive list of browser versions with StartCom cert](https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1802). If you are getting a free certificate from Gandi, why are you buying one?

Comment: @jww I was going to buy it from Gandi until I saw Gandi included it if you transfer so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will previous 301 redirect still be cached if site switches to using SSL?

I can't really answer if they will be in practice. However, I can say they *should not* be. An origin consists of a scheme, domain and port (some hand waiving). HTTP to HTTPS changes the scheme or protocol, so it should be as different as foo.com and bar.com.

See [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) on Wikipedia for more detailed examples.